# iOS simulator stuck on launch screen

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm using XCode 7.3.1, React 15.0.2 and React Native 0.26.2 (if that matters...).

I didn't do anything except installing iTerm 3 and rebooting my Mac, and since this morning, my simulator gets stuck on the splash screen. Everything used to work totally fine.
I tried to reset content and settings from the simulator, I tried the simulator with iPhone 6s, 6 and 5, and I'm still having this problem.

No error message either... Just stuck on the launch screen. The server also seems totally fine since it's fetching the files required for the index:

```
[12:20:18 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (13007ms)
[12:24:05 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[12:24:05 PM] <START> find dependencies
transformed 669/670 (100%)[12:24:29 PM] <END>   find dependencies (23705ms)
[12:24:34 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (28206ms)
[12:29:25 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[12:29:25 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (64ms)
[12:29:26 PM] <START> processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png
[12:29:26 PM] <END>   processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png (18ms)
[12:40:49 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[12:40:49 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (47ms)
[12:40:53 PM] <START> processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png
[12:40:53 PM] <END>   processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png (49ms)
[12:46:33 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[12:46:33 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (127ms)
[12:54:54 PM] <START> request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true
[12:54:54 PM] <END>   request:/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true (37ms)
[12:54:55 PM] <START> processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png
[12:54:55 PM] <END>   processing asset request src/components/login/logo.png (18ms)
```

Does anyone have a solution? Pretty please?

Comment: Can you launch other apps in the simulator? (Create an empty project and run it).

Comment: When I run an empty Master project, I get `DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator.` as en error but the project still runs.
When I run a new React Native project, I have an error from somewhere else... Very weird.

In any case, I'm not stuck on the launch screen with a new project. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I have two ideas:
1) Check your provisioning profile. Set it to automatic.
2) Quit XCode go to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData (or something like this) and delete all sub folders. Then start XCode and try again

Comment: My provisioning profile is already set to automatic, and I can't find a DerivedData folder except locally, but it is possible this is because of React Native...
I tried to delete the sub folders there once, but my app stopped working :s
I'm gonna make a copy of it and try. Is it supposed to contain 2 huge sub folders, ProjectName and ModuleCache? Or am I just supposed to delete the sub folders of ModuleCache (with barbaric sub folder names like 1HSUGHRSNBY2L)?

Comment: It is okay to delete both huge sub folders "ModuleCache" and "<ProjectName...>".
But this solves only XCode-Cleaning/Cache-Issues. I thought this may help since the problem ocurred out of nowhere.

I'm out if ideas. Did you check this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837237/app-stuck-in-splash-screen-on-ios-9-with-no-error

Comment: I didn't want to take the risk so I wanted to git clone a former version of the project pushed my mate, and for some reason, his version does compile... The problem is unresolved but I went around it.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DTAssetProviderService could not start DTXConnection with Simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200318/dtassetproviderservice-could-not-start-dtxconnection-with-simulator)

Comment: I tried the solutions suggested in that post, but none of these worked. After all, I think it must have come from the code, because using React Native, I don't recompile very often, and I must have added something that upset XCode...